# How to wait a second after each while/for loop iteration?

Tags: java, android, wait, sleep

I try to simulate a football game in Android Studio (language: Java). I generate 90 random numbers. Each iteration must represent one minute of the match. (But it is now only one second when testing). After every played minute (in this case second), the minutes played and possibly the score must be adjusted in the app. I have already tested a number of solutions that I could find on the internet, such as the Thread solution that appears everywhere. However, this does not result in the result I expected.

Expected output: An app that starts at 0 minutes and a 0-0 score, increasing the number of play minutes by 1 every second, and also adjusting the score if a goal is scored.

Actual output: A white screen for the number of milliseconds specified in the code, and then only the 'final result' of the game. For example: `90' 2-1`.

I've already tried to put the `try/catch` code elsewhere in the loop. I have also replaced `sleep` with `wait`. This always produces the same output. Can anyone tell me how I can get the number of seconds to go up live on the screen and the score changes as soon as a goal falls?

```
public void playLeagueMatch(Team team1, Team team2, TextView minuteTV,
                            TextView homeGoalsTV, TextView awayGoalsTV){

    int strength1 = team1.strength;
    int strength2 = team2.strength;
    int minutesPlayed = 0;
    double separation = Double.valueOf(strength1) / (Double.valueOf(strength1)+Double.valueOf(strength2)) * 100;

    int homeGoals = 0;
    int awayGoals = 0;

    for (minutesPlayed = 0; minutesPlayed < 91; minutesPlayed++) {
        String minuteName = Integer.toString(minutesPlayed);
        minuteTV.setText(minuteName + "'");

        int random = playMinute();

        if(random < 101){
            if(random <= separation){
                homeGoals++;
                homeGoalsTV.setText(Integer.toString(homeGoals));
            }
            else{
                awayGoals++;
                awayGoalsTV.setText(Integer.toString(awayGoals));
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The playMinute function:

```
public int playMinute(){
    Random ran = new Random();

    int random = ran.nextInt(3500) + 1;

    return random;
}
```

Comment: What is the `Thread` solution and why doesn't it work? Is that the `Thread.sleep()` in your code?

Comment: The paint function cannot run when you are waiting inside the "playLeagueMatch" function. The match needs to run on a separate thread. I can recommend AsyncTask.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, the Thread solution I mean is the Thread.sleep(). Or Thread.wait() I also tried. So, in fact I want to iterate through the for loop only once a second. Now it does all 90 iterations at once

Comment: @KYL3R I will have a look at the AsyncTask. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: if you don't like AsyncTask you can simply convert the for-loop to a normal function and check a timestamp instead of using sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `Thread.sleep()` is a bad practise. 
You can use a `Countdown Timer` and on `onTick` run your `playMinute()`

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      Log.i("seconds remaining: " ,""+ millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
         Log.i("Timer Finished");
    }  
}.start();
```

Comment: This seems to be a partial solution to me, it would be complete if you indicate how this interoperates with the (G)UI.

Comment: just update your UI inside onTick method, if you use Thread.sleep you stop the UI thread and nothing can happen...only an ANR

Comment: OK, so the (main) thread keeps running and there aren't any synchronization issues with the toolkit?

Comment: no, here the doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Comment: Yeah, I looked at it and it does use a field... Shamefully sparse documentation though.

Comment: Thanks! It took some time to make it work like I want. But it's done, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`Thread.sleep(1000)` will only sleep for 1 second because 1 second is 1000ms.

Replace it with `Thread.sleep(1 * 60 * 1000)` for a minute

Comment: Also, from Java 8 onwards, `Duration.ofMinutes(1).toMillis()` is more readable, from my perspective.